# Pandas Group/Merge Dataframe by Non-Periodic Series

Tags: pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

How do I group one DataFrame by another possibly-non-periodic Series? Mock-up below:

This is the DataFrame to be split:

```
i = pd.date_range(end="today", periods=20, freq="d").normalize()
v = np.random.randint(0,100,size=len(i))
d = pd.DataFrame({"value": v}, index=i)
```

```
>>> d
            value
2021-02-06     48
2021-02-07      1
2021-02-08     86
2021-02-09     82
2021-02-10     40
2021-02-11     22
2021-02-12     63
2021-02-13     37
2021-02-14     41
2021-02-15     57
2021-02-16     30
2021-02-17     69
2021-02-18     63
2021-02-19     27
2021-02-20     23
2021-02-21     46
2021-02-22     66
2021-02-23     10
2021-02-24     91
2021-02-25     43
```

This is the splitting criteria, grouping by the Series dates. A group consists of any ordered dataframe value `v` such that `{v}` intersects `[s,s+1)` - but as with resampling it would be nice to control the inclusion parameters.

```
s = pd.date_range(start="2019-10-14", freq="2W", periods=52).to_series()
s = s.drop(np.random.choice(s.index, 10, replace=False))
s = s.reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> s[25:29]
25   2021-01-24
26   2021-02-07
27   2021-02-21
28   2021-03-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And this is the example output... or something like it. Index is taken from the series rather than the dataframe.

```
>>> ???.sum()
            value
...
2021-01-24  47
2021-02-07  768
2021-02-21  334
...
```

Internally the groups would have this structure:

```
...
2021-01-10
        sum:        0
2021-01-24
    2021-02-06     47
        sum:       47
2021-02-07
    2021-02-07     52
    2021-02-08     56
    2021-02-09     21
    2021-02-10     39
    2021-02-11     86
    2021-02-12     30
    2021-02-13     20
    2021-02-14     76
    2021-02-15     91
    2021-02-16     70
    2021-02-17     34
    2021-02-18     73
    2021-02-19     41
    2021-02-20     79
        sum:      768
2021-02-21
    2021-02-21     90
    2021-02-22     75
    2021-02-23     12
    2021-02-24     70
    2021-02-25     87
        sum:      334
2021-03-07
        sum:        0
...
```

Comment: Are the numbers in your last example correct? I think I know what you're trying to do but I don't get those numbers exactly.

Comment: You're right, must have run it again and return a different set of random numbers.

Comment: @user19087 Always set seed for repeatability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do:

```
bucket = pd.cut(d.index, bins=s, label=s[:-1], right=False)

d.groupby(bucket).sum()
```

Comment: And to return to a DatetimeIndex:, `r.index = pd.to_datetime(r.index)`. Unless there's a better way?