# Merging pandas time series dataframes with differing time resolutions

Tags: python, pandas, reindex, pandas-resample

I have two dataframes of data each of which has datetime index. One of the datasets has a time resolution of 12.33 minutes, here `df1`, and the other has a time resolution of 1 second, here called `df2`:

```
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(minutes))
data_1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(seconds))
Channel_1=data*0.1
Channel_2=data
Channel_1_1=data_1*10
Channel_1_2=data_1*100
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': minutes, 'Channel 1': Channel_1, 'Channel 2': Channel_2})
df1 = df1.set_index('Datetime')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': seconds, 'Channel 1': Channel_1_1, 'Channel 2': Channel_1_2})
df2 = df2.set_index('Datetime')
```

Here is what `df1` and `df2` look like essentially:
[image]
[image]

I now want to merge these dataframes so that they share the same time resolution. Essentially I want to resample `df2` (ideally using `mean()`) and then place it in  new dataframe alongside the data from `df1` with the same datetime index as `df1` (i.e. so that the first values from `df2` would be the average between `df1.index[0]` and `df1.index[[1]]`). It would also be interesting to know if it is possible to average based on the midpoint between `df1.index[0]` and `df1.index[[1]]`. I have been playing with `resample`, `reindex` and `pd.merge_asof` but I just cant seem to find a solution that works.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253360/merge-series-dataframe-with-different-time-frequencies-in-python) should answer your question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375748/pandas-group-merge-dataframe-by-non-periodic-series/66376152#66376152) might be a better match to your question.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang I think you are suggesting something like this 'test = df1.index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)
bucket = pd.cut(df2.index, bins=test, labels=test[:-1],right=False)
df2.groupby(bucket).mean()'. I will test and see how I get on, thanks.